# Is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n \log (\frac{n+1}{n})$ convergent?

Tags: calculus

Determine what kinds of convergent it is: absolute convergent, conditonal convergent, or divergent. $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n \log (\frac{n+1}{n})$. well to tell that maybe it's first to seperate log? $\log (\frac{n+1}{n})$ is $\log (n+1)- \log(n)$. Then the absolute value of it is $\log (n+1)- \log(n)$. Then I notify it's best using integral test. Then for the not absolute value, I use the alternate series test, because it's alternate series with $(-1)^n$ and it's going to 0 too.

Comment: The [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) is relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Define $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n,$ where $a_n>0$. The alternating series test then says: if $|a_{n}|$ decreases monotonically and $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_{n}=0$ then the alternating series converges.

Set $a_n=\log(\frac{n+1}{n})=\log(1+\frac{1}{n})$ is monotonic decreasing for $a_n>0$ and it's limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(1+1/n)=0$$
is equal to zero. By the Leibniz criterion this series converges. Obviously the limit is not absolutely convergent.